ETL Multiple Tables with relationships using Apache Nifi
I want to use Apache Nifi to ETL data from an Oracle Database, to a SQL Server database.
The target database, has 2 tables (with a relationship) and a 1-n cardinality (with a big value of n, such as 20k or something), let's name the tables Header and Detail.
I created 2 views on my source (Oracle) database, one returning Header data and one Detail data.
So I need to fetch all Headers from Oracle view, insert each record in SQL Server, and then for each record, fetch all Details from Oracle and insert them in SQL Server.
What is best solution to iterated over records in NiFi?
As I have lots of records in Header and lots of lots of more records in Detail (as I said maybe 20k records in Detail for each record of Header), joining all and fetching all is not efficient at all.
It's job which should be run periodically.
So I started with a QueryDatabaseTable processor to read Header view (and it work incrementally), and with a PutDatabaseRecord processor I populated Header table in SQL Server. That works fine.
Now I want to fetch records of Detail view by a ExecuteSQL processor, the problem is now I need to have ID of each record of Header to pass it to query of ExecuteSQL, I have written something like select * from Detail d where d.header_id = ${ID} but it failed as ${id} was empty.
I added a SplitAvro process after inserting Header into target database, the good point is now I have a bunch of FlowFiles instead of one big one (1 for each record), then I added a FilterAttribute process, so I can just have ID attribute.
Now I don't know how to pass that attribute to next ExecuteSQL process....

"What is best solution to iterated over records in NiFi?" This type of question is likely to get the question closed as asking for opinions. You are better off asking something more specific to avoid that.

this a one time event? are you going to do delta processing periodically? how many header rows (I can times that by 20K to estimate detail records).  lots of variables at play here for sure, but always welcome to hear more details.

The general best practice when sourcing data is that if it takes a long time to pre-process the data before extraction, then you should probably post process the data instead. This would look like pulling all (or better, all "new") records over into staging tables in SQL Server. These staging tables would have no relationships or constraints, etc. Then after all the data is pulled over, you could add the records from staging to production while applying your relationships and any filters you might have.

Well I have done the job, these were the steps:

Execute SQL: just fetching non ETLed header IDs,
Convert Records: from Avro to JSON
Split JSON
Extract Text: extracted header ID to an attribute, as attributes can be passed to queries
Execute SQL: fetching header records (one by one)
Put Database Record: inserting header record
Execute SQL: fetch all detail record of the header
Put Database Record: inserting detail records in batch mode
Put SQL: mark header record, that it is ETLed, so won't be selected in future exections.

